# show a date in input with ajax modal

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

i'm working in a laravel project and i would like to show a date in input field ,
i am able to show all my rows from database ,but not the date field .
i have both tried to show it in input with type="text" and type="date" but it doesn't work .

here's the button i click to get the modal:

```
   <a type="button" class="detail-modal" 
      data-dateFin="{{$voiture->dateFin}}" >
    <h5>DETAIL</h5>
    </a>
```

my modal :

```
    <div><label class="spn text-left">date</label>
    <input type="text" name="em" class="txtmod" id="dateFin-voiture"></div>
```

my Javascript:

```
if(typeof $(this).data('dateFin') != 'undefined') {
$('#dateFin- 
voiture').val(moment($(this).data('dateFin')).format('YYYY/MM/DD'));
} else { // It's undefined
$('#dateFin-voiture').val('Please Enter Date of Birth');
}
```

in my input field it gives me Please Enter Date of Birth so it is undefined ..
the dateFin type in my database is date, in format YYYY-MM--DD

instead i am able to show my field created_at of type timestamp in my input type="text" and not type="date"

thanks for the help

Comment: old use of date('Y-m-y', strtotime(voiture->dateFin)) will not do it?

Comment: where should i use ? i have tried it inside the javascript ,but my model won't work ..

Comment: i don't know why the date is undefined ,when i try try to show directly with php i can show the date .

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
if(typeof $(this).data('dateFin') !== 'undefined')
```

Also worth mentioning that the value in your type attribute inside your anchor tag is not valid, I would suggest you use a `<button type="button">` tag for doing this.

Comment: i already tried    if(typeof $(this).data('dateFin') !== 'undefined')   it's in the code above , and i came up with the conclusion that the dateFin is undefined , i don't know what to do then . for the button it's not the problem because i tried other fields than the dateFin and it works well

Comment: -You can pass default value {{$voiture->dateFin or date('YYYY-mm-dd') }}.

Comment: @Ayoub No, it isn't, you wrote `if(typeof $(this).data('dateFin') != 'undefined')`, which is very different from `if(typeof $(this).data('dateFin') !== 'undefined')`